# Visual Studio 2015 Native Unit Test Can't Find 3rd Party .DLL

Tags: visual-studio, sqlite, unit-testing, dll, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio 2015. I created a .dll and would like to write a Unit Test. I Created a New Project using the Native Unit Test Project found in the

File | New | Project...

Visual C++ | Test | Native Unit Test Project

All works until I run it. The code requires using the SQLite .dll (sqlite3.dll). When I run the test, I get the error dialogbox:

The program can't start because sqlite3.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

I have the .dll so I suspect the message saying it is "missing" really means "unable to find".

I've attempted a lot of things to fix this, including editing the following Property Pages values:

Configuration Properties:

Debugging | Environment
VC++ Directories | Executable Directories

These changes to my project make no difference. Does anyone know how to get VS2015 testing to find 3rd party .dlls?

Thx.

**Update:**

Tried setting Configuration Properties | Debugging | Environment to:

PATH=%PATH%;$(SolutionDir)sqlite;$(LocalDebuggerEnvironment)

Then thought that I might need to reboot the Visual Studio environment for the PATH to be updated. Didn't help. It appears that if I let Visual Studio sit for a while, I get the following message:

An unhandled win32 exception occurred in StandardCollector.Service.exe [6324].

I don't know if the exception is related or not. I'm using VS2015 update #2 if that matters.

**Update:**

I got a stack dump from the crash...

> ntdll.dll!string "Enabling heap debug options\n"()  Unknown
>       DiagnosticsHub.StandardCollector.Runtime.dll!StandardCollectorService::~StandardCollectorService(void)  Unknown
>       DiagnosticsHub.StandardCollector.Runtime.dll!ATL::CComObjectCached::`vector deleting destructor'(unsigned int)  Unknown
>       DiagnosticsHub.StandardCollector.Runtime.dll!ATL::CComObjectCached<class StandardCollectorService>::Release(void)   Unknown
>       DiagnosticsHub.StandardCollector.Runtime.dll!ATL::CComObjectCached<class ATL::CComClassFactorySingleton<class StandardCollectorService> >::`vector deleting destructor'(unsigned int)   Unknown
>       DiagnosticsHub.StandardCollector.Runtime.dll!ATL::CComObjectCached >::Release(void)    Unknown
>       DiagnosticsHub.StandardCollector.Runtime.dll!ATL::CAtlComModule::Term(void) Unknown
>       DiagnosticsHub.StandardCollector.Runtime.dll!_guard_dispatch_icall_nop()    Unknown
>       ucrtbase.dll!(void)()   Unknown
>       ucrtbase.dll!__crt_seh_guarded_call::operator(),class  &,class  >(class  &&,class  &,class  &&)   Unknown
>       ucrtbase.dll!_execute_onexit_table()    Unknown
>       DiagnosticsHub.StandardCollector.Runtime.dll!operator new(unsigned __int64,struct std::nothrow_t const &)   Unknown
>       DiagnosticsHub.StandardCollector.Runtime.dll!operator new(unsigned __int64,struct std::nothrow_t const &)   Unknown
>       ntdll.dll!LdrShutdownProcess()  Unknown
>       ntdll.dll!RtlExitUserProcess()  Unknown
>       ucrtbase.dll!exit_or_terminate_process()    Unknown
>       ucrtbase.dll!common_exit()  Unknown
>       StandardCollector.Service.exe!CStandardCollectorService::OnStart(void)  Unknown
>       kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk()  Unknown
>       ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()  Unknown

Comment: I have a poor workaround. Configuration Properties | Build Events | Post-Build Event | Command Line: copy $(SolutionDir)sqlite\sqlite3.dll $(SolutionDir)$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\. I think this will need to be different for 32 vs 64 bit since the build system default stores things differently on different platforms for no particular reason I can see.